# Function transformations - what went wrong here...

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, transformation

[image]
Looking at **(b)** only,
[image]

$$ A(2,4), \quad B(4,0), \quad  C(8,4) $$

If I follow that answer in words，translation by the vector (3,0)
I know the graph will shift to the **RIGHT** by 3 units, so using the **coordinates**,
we get

$$ A(5,4), \quad B(7,0), \quad  C(11,4) $$

then if we reflect to the $y$-axis, we get

$$ A(-5,4), \quad B(-7,0), \quad  C(-11,4) $$.

However, if "shift to the **RIGHT** by 3 units", using function notation,
we should use

$$
f(x) \mapsto f(x-3)
$$

Using this we should get

$$ A(-1,4), \quad B(1,0), \quad  C(5,4) $$,
then we reflect again,

$$ A(1,4), \quad B(-1,0), \quad  C(-5,4) $$,
which is the correct answer. (obviously, the $x$ coordinate for $c$ is wrong)

**WHY** is the first method wrong????
Just moving the points to the right by adding $x$ coordinate 3,
then reflect gets the wrong answers, this is just confusing......

Answer (score 5):

You have got the order of operations mixed up. Indeed, $f(3-x) = f(-(x-3))$. However, this implies that

1. you replace $x$ by $-x$, or graphically: reflect around the $y$-axis.
2. you replace $x$ by $(x-3)$, or graphically: shift $3$ units to the right.

If we follow your order of operations, we get $f(x) \rightarrow f(x-3) \rightarrow f(-x-3)$.

It is also possible to solve this question without rewriting the function.

1. replace $x$ by $x+3$, or graphically: shift $3$ units to the left.
2. replace $x$ by $-x$, or graphically: reflect around the $y$-axis.

Both results yield $f(3-x)$.

Answer (score 4):

The description underlined in purple is actually the two transformations in the wrong order.

Translation by $\binom{3}{0}$ results in $f(x-3)$.

Now following this with a reflection in the $y$ axis results in $f(-x-3)$.

This is because in order to perform the reflection, every $x$ in the previous expression must be replaced by $-x$. This is not the same as replacing every $x-3$ with $-(x-3)$.

On the other hand, when you write $f(3-x)=f(-(x-3))$, consider firstly a reflection in the $y$ axis followed by a translation by $\binom{3}{0}$

As a sequence, $f(x)\rightarrow f(-x)\rightarrow f(-(x-3))$ and sure enough this gives the correct graph (except for the error with point $C$ of course).

Comment: but after the translation, shouldn't we consider the new variable y=x-3 as a whole????? then -y = -x+3 ????

Comment: @CasperYC I suggest you experiment with a simple function like $y=x$. The translation results in $y=x-3$ and then the reflection takes this to $y=-x-3$ not $y=-x+3$